# Cloud providers performance dataset

Tags: data-request, business

I need to perform some machine learning algorithms on a data set that contains cloud providers' performance. I need some of the following information :

- availability,
- input/output per second,
- max restore time,
- processing time,
- latency with internal compute resource

I'm already simulating this data, but I need data of real cloud providers and for some users in long time. Few numbers that show the average of those metrics won't do. I need a detailed and large data set. Is there a chance that any company provides such data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this dataset](https://data.europa.eu/euodp/data/dataset/yUBHDpCh8MDqL9Gub8qMQ) has exactly what you're looking for!

Comment: That is a low quality answer! You don't even mention it's name. Looking further, I see it is about *ICT usage in enterprises*, so it seems not to answer the question.